# Error while connecting to Oracle Endpoint in Qlik replicate "cannot load libclntsh.so.11.1"

Tags: replication, attunity

The replicate server is installed on Linux and i am trying to connect to a oracle database as source which is on a different server. While testing the connection i am getting the attached error message. The libclntsh.so is already defined in the oracle server machine. Kindly let me know the root cause of this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the oracle client (you can download the rpm from technet) on the attunity replicate server and set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.